# Scrollable div within a div

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have two divs (`content-title` and `content-items`) embedded in a fixed div (`content`). I want the `content` div to hide anything that overflows it, the `content-title` div to be fixed in place **but** the `content-items` to be scrollable.

In the snippet below, the final `<a>` element is not visible and the `content-items` will not scroll vertically. Why is this, please?

```css
.content {
  background: grey;
  max-height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-title {
  color: blue;
}

.content-items {
  color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content-items a {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .content-items a:hover {
  background: green;
  color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="content-title">
    select a city:
  </div>

  <div class="content-items">
    <a>Foo</a>
    <a>Bar</a>
    <a>Baz</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

- set `max-height` to those `div` in which you need scrollable content.
- in your case, you set `max-height` to `content` but you set the
  `overflow-y` to `content-items`.
- set `max-height` to `content-items` instead of `content`

```css
.content {
  background: grey;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-title {
  color: blue;
}

.content-items {
  color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 75px;
}

.content-items a {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .content-items a:hover {
  background: green;
  color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="content-title">
    select a city:
  </div>

  <div class="content-items">
    <a>Foo</a>
    <a>Bar</a>
    <a>Baz</a>
    <a>Foo</a>
    <a>Bar</a>
    <a>Baz</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The scrollable block needs a maximum height to give it a reason to scroll. In your example, `.content-items` displays in full height which might then be cut off by the parent's `overflow: hidden`.

I would rather set a maximum height on the `.content-items` only, like in the following modified example.

```css
.content {
  background: grey;
}

.content-title {
  color: blue;
}

.content-items {
  color: green;
  max-height: 58px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content-items a {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .content-items a:hover {
  background: green;
  color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="content-title">
    select a city:
  </div>

  <div class="content-items">
    <a>Foo</a>
    <a>Bar</a>
    <a>Baz</a>
    <a>Foo</a>
    <a>Bar</a>
    <a>Baz</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```